# Jenkins doesn't load publishers section from config.xml

Tags: xml, jenkins

I've created template `config.xml` and I use it for my feature branches jobs.

Unfortunately I discovered that `publishers` section that is responsible for post-build action is not loaded. If I open `<job url>/config.xml` I see it. But if I open `<job url>/configure` I don't see any post-build action.

Here is my `publishers` section:

```
<publishers>
  <hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver>
    <artifacts>build/*.zip,
      build/sym/*-iphoneos/*.ipa,build/test/test-results.xml,build/lcov/coverage.xml
    </artifacts>
    <allowEmptyArchive>false</allowEmptyArchive>
    <onlyIfSuccessful>false</onlyIfSuccessful>
    <fingerprint>false</fingerprint>
    <defaultExcludes>true</defaultExcludes>
  </hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver>
  <hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher plugin="cobertura@1.9.7">
    <coberturaReportFile>build/lcov/coverage.xml</coberturaReportFile>
    <onlyStable>false</onlyStable>
    <failUnhealthy>false</failUnhealthy>
    <failUnstable>false</failUnstable>
    <autoUpdateHealth>false</autoUpdateHealth>
    <autoUpdateStability>false</autoUpdateStability>
    <zoomCoverageChart>false</zoomCoverageChart>
    <maxNumberOfBuilds>0</maxNumberOfBuilds>
    <failNoReports>true</failNoReports>
    <healthyTarget>
      <targets enum-type="hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric" class="enum-map">
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>METHOD
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>8000000</int>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>LINE
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>8000000</int>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>CONDITIONAL
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>7000000</int>
        </entry>
      </targets>
    </healthyTarget>
    <unhealthyTarget>
      <targets enum-type="hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric" class="enum-map">
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>METHOD
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>0</int>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>LINE
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>0</int>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>CONDITIONAL
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>0</int>
        </entry>
      </targets>
    </unhealthyTarget>
    <failingTarget>
      <targets enum-type="hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric" class="enum-map">
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>METHOD
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>0</int>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>LINE
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>0</int>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>CONDITIONAL
          </hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric>
          <int>0</int>
        </entry>
      </targets>
    </failingTarget>
    <sourceEncoding>ASCII</sourceEncoding>
  </hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher>
  <hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver plugin="junit@1.5">
    <testResults>build/test/test-results.xml</testResults>
    <keepLongStdio>false</keepLongStdio>
    <healthScaleFactor>1.0</healthScaleFactor>
  </hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver>
  <jenkins.plugins.hipchat.HipChatNotifier plugin="hipchat@0.1.9">
    <token />
    <room>41795</room>
    <startNotification>false</startNotification>
    <notifySuccess>true</notifySuccess>
    <notifyAborted>true</notifyAborted>
    <notifyNotBuilt>false</notifyNotBuilt>
    <notifyUnstable>true</notifyUnstable>
    <notifyFailure>true</notifyFailure>
    <notifyBackToNormal>true</notifyBackToNormal>
    <startJobMessage />
    <completeJobMessage />
  </jenkins.plugins.hipchat.HipChatNotifier>
</publishers>
```

How to fix it or at least find a cause for issue?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for comment I looked to some logs in Jenkins and found next:
ConversionException: No enum const class

```
hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric.METHOD : No enum const class hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric.METHOD ---- Debugging information ---- message : No enum const class hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric.METHOD cause-exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException cause-message : No enum const class hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric.METHOD class : hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric required-type : hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric converter-type : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.enums.EnumConverter path : /project/publishers/hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher/healthyTarget/targets/entry/hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageMetric line number : 3 class[1] : java.util.EnumMap converter-type[1] : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.enums.EnumMapConverter -------------------------------, MissingFieldException: No field 'int' found in class 'hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageTarget', MissingFieldException: No field 'entry' found in class 'hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher', MissingFieldException: No field 'entry' found in class 'hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher', ConversionException: hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageTarget cannot be cast to hudson.util.DescribableList : hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageTarget cannot be cast to hudson.util.DescribableList ---- Debugging information ---- message : hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageTarget cannot be cast to hudson.util.DescribableList cause-exception : java.lang.ClassCastException cause-message : hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageTarget cannot be cast to hudson.util.DescribableList class : hudson.util.DescribableList required-type : hudson.plugins.cobertura.targets.CoverageTarget converter-type : hudson.util.DescribableList$ConverterImpl path : /project/publishers/hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher/healthyTarget line number : 5 -------------------------------, MissingFieldException: No field 'unhealthyTarget' found in class 'hudson.model.FreeStyleProject', MissingFieldException: No field 'failingTarget' found in class 'hudson.model.FreeStyleProject', MissingFieldException: No field 'sourceEncoding' found in class 'hudson.model.FreeStyleProject'
```

Comment: Have you looked in `htp://jenkins-server/administrativeMonitor/OldData/manage` to make sure you have the XML correct, or possibly the publishers don't work for the job type you have created. Can you post the rest of your XML please?

Comment: Are the newlines embedded in the closing `CoverageMetric` tags a copy and paste error, or are they also in your template file?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys with helping. I've updated a question and investigating further with it

Comment: @DaveBacher I fixed formatting in question. Original xml without new lines in the middle

Comment: Thank yo all! I've created ticket in jenkins jira https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27837